# 401 error found while sending a message to gcm

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I have facing some problems while sending a push notification to gcm server when the push notification function is executed
the following error found please help me

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

An Unauthorized error means you have given wrong key(s) at registration. Make sure you have the correct ID when you call `register(sender ID)`.

There are also other causes. For the list of other causes, refer [here](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html#auth_error).

Comment: hi koh  i have one more doubt is there any problem for using third party server .i am using http server not https is it make any issues?